# .htaccess file not redirecting url

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have this .htaccess file which simply reroute URL from primary link ex- `http://www.mywebsitename.com/somepage.php?id=some_id` to `http://www.mywebsitename.com/somepage/some_id`

Here is the code for that-

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.ashurocks.in$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ashurocks.in/$1 [R=301]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /user.php?u=$1 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^group/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /group.php?id=$1 [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /article.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

It was working properly and I was able to get the content. But now, It's not working. Whenever I visit the URL `http://www.mywebsitename.com/somepage/some_id`, it does not redirect me to `http://www.mywebsitename.com/somepage.php?id=some_id` .

Is there something wrong with this .htaccess file code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it.

I simply used `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` before the line `RewriteEngine on` and it solved my problem